# build docker image using graalvm Error: Main entry point class 'app.jar' not found com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException

Tags: java, dockerfile, graalvm

I am trying to build my Docker image using graalvm-ce but it fails showing error as:

As per oracle blog post I have mentioned the Java class also as a starting point but still it fails.

```
Error: Main entry point class 'app.jar' not found.
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Main entry point class 'app.jar' not found.
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:65)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:260)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:448)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:113)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
#Multi stage docker file

FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 AS build

ENV APP_HOME=/root/dev/app/

COPY src $APP_HOME/src

COPY pom.xml $APP_HOME/

RUN mvn -f $APP_HOME/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests



FROM oracle/graalvm-ce:19.2.0 AS build-aot

RUN ln -s /opt/graalvm-ce-19.2.0 /opt/graalvm
ENV GRAALVM_HOME=/opt/graalvm
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/graalvm
ENV PATH=${GRAALVM_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
RUN gu install native-image
COPY --from=build /root/dev/app/target/knative-spring-gke-1.0.jar /app.jar
RUN native-image --no-server -cp -jar app.jar com.arindam.knative.gke.KnativeSpringGkeApplication
#ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]

FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build-aot /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your command line for `native-image` contains `-cp -jar app.jar`. This is interpreted as `-jar` is the classpath and `app.jar` is the main class.

I think you wanted `native-image --no-server -cp app.jar com.arindam.knative.gke.KnativeSpringGkeApplication`.

Comment: It's not clear, could you please tell me what I have to do? Here I mentioned the app.jar to make a binary and KnativeSpringGkeApplication is the entry point - the main class which will launch the spring boot application.

Comment: I tried, it throws following error: 

Step 14/20 : RUN native-image --no-server -cp app.jar com.arindam.knative.gke.KnativeSpringGkeApplication
 ---> Running in 7655d13daf7e
[com.arindam.knative.gke.knativespringgkeapplication:17]    classlist:  20,719.07 ms
Error: Main entry point class 'com.arindam.knative.gke.KnativeSpringGkeApplication' not found.
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
The command '/bin/sh -c native-image --no-server -cp app.jar  returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: The first step would be to get your app working without native-image. Once that works, try replacing `java` with `native-image`.
Does `app.jar` contain the entry-point class (`com.arindam.knative.gke.KnativeSpringGkeApplication`)?

Answer (score 2):

If HW.class to be compiled, say

```
native-image HW
```

not

```
native-image HW.class
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with a basic "Hello World" program. The problem arose because I initially compiled the Java file using Corretto Java 17 and then attempted to build a native image of that class using the command `native-image Hello`.

However, I resolved the issue by removing the existing class file and recompiling it using the GraalVM JDK. Afterward, when I executed the same command, it started working as expected.